# Fill array of struct with concurrent for loop results in malloc error

Tags: swift, struct, concurrency

In a SceneKit scene, I would like to load the vertices of an object from a text file. After that I create the SCNGeometry out of these vertices.

To store the position and color information, I created a struct called `Vertex`:

```
struct Vertex {
    var x: Float, y: Float, z: Float
}
```

#### Working Example

Everything is working, when using a **single** thread to read the data and store the it in the vertices array:

```
// read file as lines of string
var n = totalNumberOfVertices
var lines = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")

// create array for vertices
var vertices = Array(repeating: Vertex(x:0, y:0, z:0), count: n)

// fill vertices array
for i in 0...(n-1) {
    let elements = lines[i].components(separatedBy: " ")

    vertices[i].x = Float(elements[0])!
    vertices[i].y = Float(elements[1])!
    vertices[i].z = Float(elements[2])!
}

// create geometry and so on ...
```

#### Problem

To increase the performance, I would like to use **GDS** to perform a concurrent for loop. Because all the lines are there, I just need different line indexes, to store the data in different array indexes. So it should be possible to parallel it with ease:

```
// fill vertices array concurrent
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: n - 1) { (i) in
    let elements = lines[i].components(separatedBy: " ")

    vertices[i].x = Float(elements[0])!
    vertices[i].y = Float(elements[1])!
    vertices[i].z = Float(elements[2])!
}
```

But now I always get an error during setting the different vertex values (`x, y, z`). The error tells me that a pointer was not freed, but I can not see what kind of pointer he is talking about. Maybe I misunderstand something of the underlaying implementation of structs in Swift.

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x113190000: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong, because I am not writing Swift that often, but I believe that I do not have any visible (directly in my code) concurrency problem.

#### Additional

Another strange thing is following:  If I get the reference to the struct element, I am not able to set the values. Is a struct always returned `byval`? Maybe it has something todo with this phenomenon.

```
var vertex = vertices[i]

// this is not working
// vertices[i] is still 0 after that
vertex.x = Float(elements[0])!
vertex.y = Float(elements[1])!
vertex.z = Float(elements[2])!
```

Comment: Struct is passed by value. Therefore the `vertex` you are setting is not a reference to the element in the array. It's a copy. You mention increasing performance but you are using a verbose text file for data. Have you looked at Model I/O which works with SceneKit?

Comment: @SteveO'Connor Yeah, that's what I thought. Thanks for clarification. Pointclouds are sometimes delivered in ascii format (XYZ, PLY, PTX ...), so I can not change that.